# How Can I Update A React Component From a Separate Sibling Component in a Separate File?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, firebase-authentication, web-component

I am trying to have my navbar update to show the user logged in info after they attempt to login and it is successful. Here's the relevant code files:

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <NavBar />
            <Main />
          </header>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

NavBar.js

```
const NavBar = () => {
  const [userInfo, SetUserInfo] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    SetNavBar(null);
  }, [])

  function SetNavBar(element){
    var user = auth.currentUser;
    console.log(auth.currentUser);

    if (user){
      var userInfo = 
        React.createElement('div', {id : 'userDiv'},
          React.createElement('span', {id : 'userDisplayName'}, user.email),
          React.createElement('span', {id : 'signoutSpan'}, 
            '(', 
            React.createElement('button', {id : 'signoutButton', onClick : (e) => SignOutUser(e.target)}, 'Signout'),
            ')'
          )
        );
      SetUserInfo(userInfo);
    }
    else if(element != null && element.nodeName === 'A'){
      var urlTO = element.href;
        
      if(!urlTO.includes("login") && !urlTO.includes("signup")){
        var userLoginSignupElement = 
          React.createElement('span', {id : 'loginSignupOptions'}, 
            React.createElement(Link, {to : '/login', onClick : (e) => SetNavBar(e.target)}, 'Login'), 
            '/',
            React.createElement(Link, {to : '/signup', onClick : (e) => SetNavBar(e.target)}, 'Signup')
          );
      }
      else{
        var userLoginSignupElement = null;
      }
      SetUserInfo(userLoginSignupElement);
    }
    else{
      var userLoginSignupElement = 
        React.createElement('span', {id : 'loginSignupOptions'}, 
          React.createElement(Link, {to : '/login', onClick : (e) => SetNavBar(e.target)}, 'Login'), 
          '/',
          React.createElement(Link, {to : '/signup', onClick : (e) => SetNavBar(e.target)}, 'Signup')
        );
      SetUserInfo(userLoginSignupElement);
    }
  }

  async function SignOutUser(element){
    try{
      await signOut(auth);
      SetNavBar(null)
    }
    catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <nav id='navBar'>
        <div id='logoTitleDiv'>
          <img id='navBarLogo' src={logo} alt='Skeeters logo.'></img>
          <Link to='/' onClick={e => SetNavBar(e.target)}>
            <h2 id='pageHeader'>DJSkeeterB</h2>
          </Link>
        </div>
        {userInfo}
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

Main.js

```
const Main = () => {
    return (
        <div id='main'>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path='/' element={<SongRequests/>}/>
                <Route exact path='/upcoming' element={<Upcoming/>}/>
                <Route exact path='/signup' element={<Signup/>}/>
                <Route exact path='/login' element={<Login/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Main;
```

Login.js

```
const Login = () => {
  const [navigateToHome, SetNavigateToHome] = useState(false);
  const [userEmail, SetUserEmail] = useState('');
  const [userPassword, SetUserPassword] = useState('');

  const userEmailRef = useRef('');
  userEmailRef.current = userEmail;

  const userPasswordRef = useRef('');
  userPasswordRef.current = userPassword;

  const LoginToFirebase = async () => {
    try {
      await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, userEmailRef.current, userPasswordRef.current);
      console.log(auth.currentUser);
      document.getElementById('emailInput').innerHTML = '';
      document.getElementById('passwordInput').innerHTML = '';

      SetUserEmail('');
      SetUserPassword('');

      SetNavigateToHome(true);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  if(navigateToHome === true){
    return <Navigate to='/'/>;
  }
  return (
      <div id='loginDiv'>
        <div>
          <h2>Login</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Email: </label>
          <input id='emailInput' type='email' placeholder='example@gmail.com' onChange={e => SetUserEmail(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Password: </label>
          <input id='passwordInput' type='password' placeholder='Password' onChange={e => SetUserPassword(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>
        <button onClick={e => LoginToFirebase()}>Submit</button>
        <div>
          <span id='alreadySignedUpSpan'>
            <Link to='/signup'>Not registered? Signup here</Link>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Essentially I have my app show the navbar at all times, and depending on page or user authenticated it updates to be different. The component `Main` is using react-router-dom to link a few pages currently. After the user signs in or signs up on `Login.js` or `Signup.js` they are redirected to the main page. They are successfully logged in using firebase authentication. After the redirect they land on the main page but the navbar isn't updating as I don't know how to call for a state change from what's happening in `Login.js` to affect `NavBar.js`.

The navbar has no way of knowing this was a successful authentication it seems. I tried treating `auth` and `auth.currentUser` as states to see if when they update they could be used in a `useEffect(() => {}, [auth])` way to call the SetNavBar function in `NavBar.js`.

How can I update my component `NavBar`, at the end of my function `LoginToFirebase()` function?

Comment: You shouldn't use `document.getElementById` in react. What you're trying to do is [`control`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) the input state. That's done by adding the value attribute to the input like this: `<input id='emailInput' value={userEmail}/>` and `<input id='passwordInput' value={userPassword} />`.

Comment: @Adam I see thanks for the advice, I'll change my setup to reflect that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By lifting `userEmail` [state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to your App component (and perhaps all the login functionality) and making your `Login` component accept a prop of `onClickLogin`.

Comment: So `App` would now contain the state and logic of logging in, that is currently stored in the `Login` component. Then I would use a useEffect hook on the state, but how do I call the function from `NavBar` in `App`?

Comment: @Kastor438 There's no need for a `useEffect` hook on the state. You would simply pass `userEmail` state in the `App` component as a prop into `NavBar`. The value of that prop - null/undefined, or some string - tells you if a user is logged in and dictates what you should render - e.g. you don't need that function and state in the `NavBar` component - just remove it. Use the `userEmail` prop as the source of truth for the user's logged in state.

Comment: I tried what you said, I don't quite follow how to update the props state in the child. I managed to send the state the `App` component has to all the files perhaps in future use of it. I get it to the `Login` component. How would I set the state to be changed in the `Login` component so that it passes back up? Or am I just totally misunderstanding the steps you mean?

Comment: @Kastor438 there is no state in the login component either. You need a single source of truth for the userEmail state, and that’s the App component.

Comment: I got it working, passing a handler down to `Login`, which updates the state in `App`, and as that state changes my component get updated in `NavBar` now. I appreciate you help and the state up article!

Comment: @Kastor438 - when done right, react is deceptively easy and simple (I hope you see that). When done poorly, it appears impossible. Whenever something feels really hard in react, it's because you're doing it wrong ;)